# Angular 2: How to create an array in a service that a component will observe changes to?

Tags: service, typescript, angular, observable, ionic2

I want my `NotificationsBellComponent` to receive changes to the array in the service. Assume the `_LocalStorageService` is sending back data correctly.

**Q) How do I get my component to receive changes to the service collection when they happen?**

*The component so far:*

```
@Component({
    selector: 'notifications-bell',
    directives: [],
    templateUrl: 'build/components/notificationsBell/notificationsBell.html',
    styles: [`
        button{
            background: none !important;
            background-color: none !important;
            box-shadow: none !important;
        }
    `]
})
export class NotificationsBellComponent {

    private notifications: string[];

    constructor(
        private _platform: Platform,
        private _nav: NavController,
        private _events: Events,
        private _ConfigService: ConfigurationService,
        private _NotificationService: NotificationService
    ) {
        this.notifications = this._NotificationService.notifications;
    }
}
```

*The service so far:*

```
@Injectable()
export class NotificationService {

  public notifications: string[];

  constructor(
    private _ConfigService: ConfigurationService,
    private _LocalStorageService: LocalStorageService,
    private _I8nService: I8nService,
    private _events: Events
  ) {
    this.getData();
  }

  getData() {
    this._LocalStorageService.getNotifications().then((data) => {
      var list: string[] = [];
      if (data.res.rows.length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.res.rows.length; i++) {
          list.push(data.res.rows.item(i).notification);
        }
      }
      this.notifications = list;
    });
  }

  addItem(description: string) {
    this._LocalStorageService.addNotification(description).then(() => {
      this.getData();
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getData()` assigns `notifications` to a new `list` array each time the promise resolves.  Your component will still have a reference to the original `list` array.

Instead of assigning a new array each time, just clear it out and `push()` the new data onto it:

```
export class NotificationService {
  public notifications: string[];
  getData() {
    this._LocalStorageService.getNotifications().then((data) => {
      this.notifications.length = 0;  // clear array, but keep same reference
      if (data.res.rows.length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.res.rows.length; i++) {
          this.notifications.push(data.res.rows.item(i).notification);
        }
      }
    });
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: Such a simple solution.  Such a rookie error on my part, duh...Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

By not creating an array in the service.

In doing so, you're "breaking the chain" of this observable sequence: You want an observable in your component, you're (apparently) getting an observable from your `LocalStorageService`, so your goal should be to model this as a stream all the way through rather than breaking it up in your service.

Something like:

```
@Injectable()
export class NotificationService {

  public notifications$: Observable<string[]>;

   constructor(
     private _ConfigService: ConfigurationService,
     private _LocalStorageService: LocalStorageService,
     private _I8nService: I8nService,
     private _events: Events
   ) {
      this.notifications$ = this._LocalStorageService.getNotifications()
          .map(notifications => {
              // modify the notifications however you need to her
          }) 

   }
}
```

Then, in your service, you can `subscribe()` to `service.notifications$`.

Comment: `this._LocalStorageService.getNotifications()` returns a `Promise`, not `Observable` FYI.  2 questions on this: 1) Why is this better than the answer by Mark below, which works.  2) How do I `subscribe()` in my component class given your example?